# probe-scsi-all shows two disks with the same PhyNum

Tags: hard-drive, scsi, solaris-10

I'm attempting to remotely determine the physical location of two disks in an Oracle SPARC T4-1 server prior to performing a Solaris install.  Because the disks use World Wide Names (WWNs), the Oracle documentation recommends using the OBP command "probe-scsi-all", and associating the SASDeviceName (WWN) with the PhyNum value to determine which slot each disk is in.  However, that command reports both disks as being in slot 0; in reality, one is in slot 0, and the other is in slot 4.  Here's the command output I'm seeing:

```
 {0} ok probe-scsi-all

 /pci@400/pci@2/pci@0/pci@4/scsi@0

 FCode Version 1.00.61, MPT Version 2.00, Firmware Version 9.00.00.00

 Target 9 
   Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109030SESUN300G A31A    585937500 Blocks, 300 GB
   SASDeviceName 5000cca0164a9f04  SASAddress 5000cca0164a9f05  PhyNum 0 
 Target a 
   Unit 0   Removable Read Only device   TEAC     DV-W28SS-V       1.0B
   SATA device  PhyNum 6 

 /pci@400/pci@1/pci@0/pci@4/scsi@0

 FCode Version 1.00.61, MPT Version 2.00, Firmware Version 9.00.00.00

 Target 9 
   Unit 0   Disk   HITACHI  H109030SESUN300G A31A    585937500 Blocks, 300 GB
   SASDeviceName 5000cca0164be610  SASAddress 5000cca0164be611  PhyNum 0
```

In this instance, the second device listed (be610) should have PhyNum 4, according to the slot numbering diagram on the front of the server.  When I physically swap the disks and re-issue the command, device be610 is then listed first, but both devices still display PhyNum 0.  I've tried finding an explanation for this in the Oracle documentation or on Google, but I haven't had any luck; I'm guessing because this isn't actually a "problem", and it's my lack of knowledge that's hindering me from framing the question correctly.

---

Does anyone know why those PhyNum values would be identical, or how else I might determine which slot each disk is in, using nothing but OBP or ILOM?  I need to have a reliable method of determining which disk is in which slot, prior to actually installing the OS on the server, and the Solaris installer just lists the disks alphabetically by WWN.

I appreciate any advice anyone can offer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/pci@400/pci@2/pci@0/pci@4/scsi@0` uses the first 4 slots and numbers them from phys 0-3

`/pci@400/pci@1/pci@0/pci@4/scsi@0` uses the next 4 slots after but it still starts the phys num from 0-3 which is rality would be slot 4-7

The difference is `pci@0` and `pci@1` in the device path which show they are on different paths.

Comment: Thanks!  That had been driving me crazy; I can finally update the document I was writing.